# exec from terminal application killing the terminal

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, exec

I have written a small ncurses tool to run applications. What I want to achieve is that after I press enter and I successfully create the new process I want to exit my ncurses application and close the terminal.
I run my application with `termite -e my_app` (every other terminal emulator which has the -e option should be fine, too). The terminal would probably close after my_app exits, but I can't get the parent to exit.

I tried adding an `exit(0)` to the location in the code marked with a comment, but in this case I can no longer open up an application (I guess it exits immediately when its parent exits).

I also tried using exec directly, without forking. But in this case the terminal emulator as parent of my_app and its replacement will keep running until the application exits.

```
static void
handle_enter (enum mode mode, char *buf, struct appdata *appdata, int i)
{
  pid_t pid;

  if (mode == EXEC)
    {
      if (i == -1)
        return;
      if (strcmp (buf, appdata[i].name) == 0)
        {
          pid = fork();
          if (pid < 0)
            report_run_error ("Could not fork", NULL);
          else if (pid == 0)
            {
              execvp (appdata[i].args[0], appdata[i].args);
              report_run_error ("Could not run: %s", appdata[i].name);
            }
          /* tried exit here */
        }
      else
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is my_app is closing, sending SIGHUP to its children, which includes the forked process. When the forked process gets SIGHUP, it forwards it to its children, which include the exec'd program, so that dies too.

Sounds like you want something similar to nohup, which doesn't respond to SIGHUP, or the shell built-in, "disown", which effectively chooses not to send SIGHUP to the exec'd process on exit.

Simplest thing to do would be to

a) call signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN) before calling execvp, which will prevent your forked process from dying when it gets SIGHUP.

or

b) copy appdata[i].args with adding "nohup" in front, and call execvp on that. nohup does (a) for you.

minimal example of the first option:

```
void main(){
  char * cmd[3] = {"sleep", "1337", 0};
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
    printf("Could not fork");
  else if (pid == 0)
    {
      signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
      execvp (cmd[0], cmd);
      printf ("Could not run");
    }
}
```

If you run the above you will see it dies immediately but leaves sleep orphaned (find it with top or ps)

Answer (score -2):

My idea is getting your program PID (process id), find it's parent PID (the terminal shell) and kill it with shell command "kill -9", then quit.

Comment: I tried `kill (getppid(), 9);` in the childs code (before the exec) and `wait (0);` in the parents code. Both exit immediately.